# Socket IO econnrefused on port 3000

Tags: javascript, mysql, linux, node.js, socket.io

I'm running a node server using socket.io 0.9.16 and after restarting 
my server recently I got the above mentioned error:

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED\n    at exports._errnoException (util.js:676:11)\n    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:938:19)\n    --------------------\n    at Protocol._enqueue (
/var/www/node_modules/mysql-activerecord/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:110:48)\n    at Protocol.handshake (/var/www/node_modules/mysql-activerecord/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protoc
ol.js:42:41)\n    at Connection.connect (/var/www/node_modules/mysql-activerecord/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:98:18)\n    at Connection._implyConnect (/var/www/node_modules/mysql-activerecord
/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:296:10)\n    at Connection.query (/var/www/node_modules/mysql-activerecord/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:154:8)\n    at get (/var/www/node_modules/mysql-ac
tiverecord/index.js:387:15)\n    at Manager.<anonymous> (/var/www/mutual.js:101:71)\n    at Manager.authorize (/var/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:910:31)\n    at Manager.handleHandshake (/
var/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:786:8)\n    at Manager.handleRequest (/var/www/node_modules/socket.io/lib/manager.js:593:12)',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true }
```

nmap localhost returns:

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-07-22 21:02 EDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.0000050s latency).
Hostname localhost resolves to 2 IPs. Only scanned 127.0.0.1
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
Not shown: 992 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
587/tcp  open  submission
3000/tcp open  ppp
3306/tcp open  mysql
9000/tcp open  cslistener
```

netstate -an | grep "LISTEN " returns

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
...
```

iptables --list returns

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:3000

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Relevant server code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql-activerecord'),
    marked = require('marked'),
    conn = new mysql.Adapter({
            server: 'server-name',
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
            database: 'database'
    }),
    moment = require('moment');

var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);
```

Relevant client code:

```
a=io.connect("http://server-name:3000/",{query:stuff})
```

Thanks in advance for the help. Let me know if you need anymore information. Sorry
if this post is a bit long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ECONNREFUSED has nothing to do with socket.io, if you look at the backtrace provided in the error, you can see it's coming from the `mysql` module. So it appears that your mysql server is not listening on `server-name` on port 3306 (or at least something is blocking access to it).

Comment: nmap shows 3306 is being used by mysql, and when I listed out port activity it showed the same thing. Do you know what might be blocking it?

Comment: It might be listening on 3306, but which interface(s)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by which interface it's using? And how do I figure that out (sorry if noob question)?

Comment: You can use `netstat -aln` to show the addresses that are listening on which ports. Basically `server-name` needs to either be a hostname that resolves to the ip (at port 3306) in `netstat -aln` or `server-name` **is** that same ip.

Comment: Hey, I fixed the problem. The server-name was indeed incorrect. Thanks so much for the help. You relieved the headache I've been having for the pasts few days. Cheers.